# How to obtain records of a specific month in SQL by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm using Postgres 9.1 and try to get records from a table knowing the given month and should know if the date type date field contains the month.

This is my query:

```
SELECT consejo.numero,consejo.fecha FROM consejo WHERE MONTH(consejo.fecha) = 2
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR: There is no month function (date)
>   LINE 1: ... T consejo.numero, consejo.fecha council FROM WHERE MONTH (cons ...
>   
>   HINT: No function matches the name and types of arguments. You may need to add explicit type conversion.

might be wrong?

Comment: You should compare using `BETWEEN` or `>`  to make your query [SARGable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Comment: Are you sure you want to filter on just the month, and not the year and month?

Comment: Where in the manual did you find the `month()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgresql there is no `MONTH` function available. You can use [**`EXTRACT`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) instead:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM consejo.fecha) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use PostgreSQL's date_part() function:

```
 WHERE date_part('month', consejo.fecha) = 2
```

Look at the reference guide:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html